# Error OAuth 2.0 in YouTube JAVA API

Tags: java, api, authentication, youtube, oauth-2.0

I am trying to retrieve the user contacts from a YouTube profile. While using OAuth 2.0 in YouTube JAVA API, I am getting this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.mortbay.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at Signin.main(Signin.java:123)
```

I referred to some other pages and updated the port number in Google API Console. But still i get the same error. 
Is there any other method to use authentication in my program. Thanks.

Comment: Please, post your code, not just the error.

Answer (score 0):

This, in fact, has nothing to do with the YouTube API. It appears that your code is attempting to start an embedded [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) server. That Jetty server is attempting to bind its connector to a port (most likely 8080) that is already in use on your machine.

There are two potential solutions from what I can gather:

1. Figure out if you actually need to be running an embedded Jetty to simply call the YouTube API (you probably don't). Eliminate the Jetty server if not.
2. If you do, deconflict the ports by either shutting down what is already using the port that Jetty is attempting to use, or reconfigure Jetty to use a different port.